# Why my m.2 super fast laptop takes so long to boot up Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, ssd

I have lenovo x1 yoga (m.2 ssd, 16gb ram, i7) and Ubuntu takes good couple+ minutes to get to the log-in screen.
I have just the home folder encrypted.

When it came with windows 10 by default it was booting in less than 10 seconds to the log-in screen.

It spends all the time booting at the purple Ubuntu screen with the dots beneath, blinking.

Then shows up the log-in screen and is fast as hell again.

So, why the extraordinary long boot time?

here is the  systemd-analyze blame output

> ```
>       6.302s apt-daily.service
>       5.851s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>       3.242s iio-sensor-proxy.service
>       2.676s fwupd.service
>        464ms systemd-resolved.service
>        424ms accounts-daemon.service
>        393ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
>        382ms grub-common.service
>        333ms lightdm.service
>        332ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
>        326ms upower.service
>        293ms alsa-restore.service
>        283ms pppd-dns.service
>        248ms bluetooth.service
>        172ms ModemManager.service
>        153ms apparmor.service
>        147ms gpu-manager.service
>        141ms NetworkManager.service
>        125ms irqbalance.service
>        125ms apport.service
>        108ms systemd-timesyncd.service
>        102ms networking.service
>         93ms packagekit.service
>         91ms udisks2.service
>         89ms snapd.socket
>         65ms keyboard-setup.service
>         58ms virtualbox.service
>         55ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
>         51ms repowerd.service
>         50ms systemd-logind.service
>         47ms speech-dispatcher.service
>         46ms avahi-daemon.service
>         46ms thermald.service
>         35ms user@1000.service
>         33ms systemd-journald.service
>         30ms polkit.service
>         27ms systemd-udevd.service
>         27ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
>         25ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7979\x2dE409.service
>         24ms rsyslog.service
>         22ms snapd.autoimport.service
>         21ms colord.service
>         18ms ureadahead-stop.service
>         17ms plymouth-start.service
>         16ms setvtrgb.service
>         15ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
>         13ms systemd-modules-load.service
>         13ms wpa_supplicant.service
>         12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
>         11ms plymouth-read-write.service
>         10ms dev-hugepages.mount
>          9ms kmod-static-nodes.service
>          9ms systemd-update-utmp.service
>          8ms ufw.service
>          8ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
>          8ms systemd-sysctl.service
>          8ms boot-efi.mount
>          6ms dns-clean.service
>          6ms systemd-remount-fs.service
>          5ms systemd-journal-flush.service
>          5ms openvpn.service
>          5ms dev-mqueue.mount
>          4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
>          4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
>          3ms rtkit-daemon.service
>          3ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service
>          3ms systemd-random-seed.service
>          3ms console-setup.service
>          3ms systemd-rfkill.service
>          2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
>          2ms resolvconf.service
>          2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
>          2ms swapfile.swap
> ```

Comment: Was your Windows 10 using [Fast Startup mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)?

Comment: No idea, installing ubuntu fresh was the first thing I did.
However Is it normal for ubuntu to bootup that long on m2 ssd?

Comment: In my experience with NVMe SSD Windows boots in about 8 seconds and Ubuntu about 11 seconds. You can suppress your first two time consuming services: `apt-daily.service` and `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`. See: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/4-tips-speed-up-ubuntu-16-04